# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'letterboxdpy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv, modulenotfounderror

I am encountering an issue while attempting to use the letterboxdpy module within a Python virtual environment. Despite successfully installing the module using pip, confirming its presence in the virtual environment's site-packages, and ensuring the correct Python binary is used, I am unable to import the letterboxdpy module in my script.

### Steps

1. Created a virtual environment using python3 -m venv myenv.
2. Installed the letterboxdpy module within the virtual environment using pip install letterboxdpy.
3. Attempted to import the letterboxdpy module in a script within the virtual environment.

### Expected Behavior:

I expect to be able to import the letterboxdpy module without encountering any errors within my virtual environment.

### Actual Behavior:

I receive a ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import the letterboxdpy module within the virtual environment. The Python script is unable to locate the module despite it being installed.

### Environment:

Python Version: 3.9.6 
MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1

### Additional Information

Output of `pip list` within the virtual environment:

```
Package      Version
------------ -------
letterboxdpy 4.0
pip          21.2.4
setuptools   58.0.4
```

Output of `pip show letterboxdpy` within the virtual environment:

```
Name: letterboxdpy
Version: 4.0
Summary: A letterboxd webscraper
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: Nicholas Cassarino <nmcassa804@outlook.com>
License: 
Location: /Users/userOne/Desktop/Env/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

### Notes

I have verified that the correct Python binary within the virtual environment is being used (/Users/userOne/Desktop/Env/myenv/bin/python). Additionally, I attempted to explicitly include the letterboxdpy module path in sys.path within the script, but the issue persists.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wheel for `letterboxdpy` 4.0 is buggy — it installs `src/letterboxdpy` instead of `letterboxdpy` and it doesn't contain `__init__.py`. Install an older version this way:

```
pip install -U "letterboxdpy < 4"
```

Please note double quotes.

*Upd*. I reported the bug and the author promptly fixed it in version 4.2.

```
pip install -U letterboxdpy
```

or

```
pip install -U "letterboxdpy >= 4.2"
```

Comment: I reported the bug: https://github.com/nmcassa/letterboxdpy/issues/10